# Rewrite resource URL in Apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting, http-status-code-404

I'm making an Ajax navigation similar to the one that YouTube and Facebook have and I want to do the next:

When the user goes to an specific URL in the address bar, ex:

http://example.com/some-resource

If some-resource is not found in the server Apache will throw a 404, instead I want to redirect to the page that handles the nagivation (index.html) and let it handle the rest.

In other words, I don't want that Apache displays an error page, I want to ALWAYS redirect the 404 to index.html with the specified URL.

Ex:

http://example.com/some-resource <- some-resource doesn't exist, then go to index.html with the new URL.

http://example.com/img/logo.jpg <- Resource exist, don't do anything.

How can I do that? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ /index.html [L,R]
```

Alternatively you can also do it by using `ErrorDocument 404` like this:

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://example.com/index.html
```